# Geth and qtminer: 0 balance after 2 days with 3.2MH/s

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, windows, qtminer

I'm using Geth + QtMiner:

```
qtminer.exe -s asia1.ethpool.org:3333 -u 0x37830e9f76198f82cdb81821a7a380c82e24b4f9.maplerichie -G --opencl-platform 1
```

My average hashrate is just around 3.2MH/s but benchmark can go up to 10MH/s, is there any problem with my syntax or configuration?

After two day mining, the balance return at geth console is still zero (0), check with command `web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")`, is this normal?

From the calculation, I should already get 0.05 ETH if hashrate is 3.2MH/s.
Will the mining speed affected by broadband speed? I have a 30Mbps connection only.

Windows 10, with GTX960 GPU.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ethpool is a predictable solo mining pool. You will only get paid out after you have submitted enough shares equal to finding a block at the current hash rate. [See your stats here](http://ethpool.org/miners/37830e9f76198f82cdb81821a7a380c82e24b4f9).

> Approximate time to next block: 7 months

It will be better if you switch to another pool with a different payout scheme.

> Want the same mining pool quality like ethpool.org but with a PPLNS style payment mode? Check out our new mining pool: [ethermine.org](http://ethermine.org/)